# Binary Search an object in a sorted vector with some meaningless entries as interference

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector `vector<int> A`, where all non-zero values have been well sorted. However, there are also some `0`s stored inside which we treat it as meaningless. There are no duplicates of non-zero elements in the vector. For example, `A` is some kind of vector like `[0,0,5,0,6,9,10,21,0,40,0]`. Now given a number `x (x!=0)`, we should find the first position in this vector such that the value here `>= x`. For example, if `x == 10`, the return value should be `6` since `A[6] == 10`; if `x == 23` the return value should be `9` since `A[9] == 40` and it's the first element larger than `10`.

I know how to write my own code to implement a binary search considering the meaningless `0`. However I'm thinking how to use STL existing functions to implement it. A straight-forward idea is to extract all non-zeros elements to another `vector<int> B`, recording each element's original position in `A`, apply `std::lower_bound` to `B` and finally get the position in `A`. However since the extracting step will be of complexity `O(N)`, this idea will be meaningless though works.

Could anyone help me with another idea with STL functions? The complexity needs to be no larger than `log(N)`.

Note: some people said if the vector `A` contains all zeros, we have no way to do it in `log(N)`. Please consider it as a worst case. What I mean by `log(N)` is, if `A` contains no zeros, it should be `log(N)`; Of course, with increasing number of zeros, the efficiency must be decreasing, yet this should be required.

Comment: The existing `std` algorithms are either going to require a fully ordered sequence, or are going to be O(n). I don't see a way around it.

Comment: Are you saying that x could be zero?  Since zero can't be greater than anything I don't see how the zeros cause a problem in the searching algorithm. (Ahh.  Never mind.  If the zeros are randomly throughout then I see why they are a problem).

Comment: Binary search is only going to give you an indication of presence.  It doesn't tell you where the value was found.  He wants the position found, which is why he is already looking at lower_bound.

Comment: @shawn1874, the given number x is sure not to be zero. see my revised editing.

Comment: @C. Wang, my original thinking was offbase anyway.  Sorry.  The zeros throughout will not work with a binary search of any kind because they will cause the lower_bound to be incorrect.

Comment: "The complexity needs to be no larger than log(N)." ... is that average case complexity? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity

Comment: @amdn, yes, it can be viewed as an average complexity, please see my revised post.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in `O(logn)`. Consider the case where all the elements in the vector are zero. You can in no way find an algorithm that will do this in less than `O(n)` time.